# Netbeans IDE version to use

Tags: ide, netbeans

I would like to know which version/flavor of Netbeans I have to use for working predominantly with Java 8 SDK. I will be using tools like Maven, Groovy, Gradle and  other EE frameworks like Spring boot. The netbeans homepage seem to be long and dont seem to have a straight forward answer. Google didnt help either. Should I try apache netbeans and explicitly set JRE/JDK version in IDE to Java 8? Will it create some issues while building existing project code from Git/SVN? I am looking for recommendations from folks of this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the latest version of NetBeans running on the latest version of Java. This will give you the best performance, and the best reliability with all possible bug fixes.

Within your project, configure for building to Java 8. The compiler will prevent you from calling on classes or methods from later versions.

This approach is quite common, to run your tools in the latest but aim your project  at a earlier version of Java.

If using Maven, set the version of Java used for your app in your POM. See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

You may need to do a clean-and-build on your project, and a Maven `clean`.